# ASP.NET WEB API Data Access Layer with Stored procedures

Tags: asp.net-web-api, data-access-layer

I am very new to the MVC frame work and ASP.NET WEB API

I have been Building Web Application using ASP.NET AJAX with n-tier architecture with data as Stored Procedure Only for quite some time.

We are trying to upgrade one of our Products to develop using HTML5 ASP.NET WEB API and We would like to keep our DAL and stored Procedures intact and add a service Layer using ASP.NET WEB API or WCF Data Services on top of the DAL and HTML5 Presentation layer will hit the service layer for the data.

can you suggest if this is a possible scenario where we want to keep the database stored Procedures and DAL intact?

As I have noticed the support for Stored Procedures in EF5 needs a lot more maturity to support some of our stored Procedures with multi table datasets I know there are workarounds on this. I have seen EF 6 Alpha Specifications and I am excited about the features.

Does any one have a link to a tutorial or a sample of ASP.NET WEB API Service layer on top of a Data Access Layer? OR can you make some suggestions or point me to right direction please

If I have to make a wild guess on how I want to implement a solution for our current problem. I would say.

Present DAL gives us Dataset and wrapper for DataTable in the dataset to Convert to IQueryable and use them in ServiceLayer skip the whole EF workarounds.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

In reality you could to this. You could place your service logic into Web API, however, I wouldn't do this. I would rather add one more layer of abstraction in order to keep the API as lightweight and as simple as possible. According to your scenario you have something like this:

1. Back-end DB Server with Stored Procedures
2. Data Access Layer component for working with number 1, back-end DB.

Now you want to build API on top of 2. My suggestion to you would be to add Service layer (aka Business Logic layer) where you would put additional logic like calculations, if necessary additional validation, messaging services, etc.

And then on top of the service layer I would add Web API. So at the end your layering could be something like this:

1. Back-end DB Server with Stored Procedures
2. Data Access Layer component for working with number 1, back-end DB.
3. Service Layer (Business Logic)
4. ASP.NET Web API
5. HTML5 Client

The idea behind this is that sometime again in the future, when you need to add additional features to your product, you would do it in the service layer. Don't go on and add complexity to your Web API. Think about maintenance, testing and future expansion.

Comment: Any online examples of this approach?

Comment: Not so sure about the Business Logic in the Web API. Your View Models have to make an API call just for validation.